# Solar flare prevention

Tags: internal-consistency, solar-system

Would it be possible to prevent or divert a massive solar flare (0.035 watts per meter^2 1-8 Angstrom Wavelength or approximately X30 on the solar flare scale https://www.spaceweatherlive.com/en/help/what-are-solar-flares)? If so, how would we do it (what are the energy requirements, proximity requirements, size of vessel -- computable)?

For instance how hard would it be to change the sun's magnet reconnection to cancel the flare? Or better yet divert it?

Comment: "Solar Flare" or "Solar Mass Ejection"?

Comment: In one word: *No.* Or in a picture: https://www.relfe.com/Images/Solar_System_3.jpg

Comment: You didn't include the "hard science" tag, so is this Space Opera in the E. E. “Doc” Smith mould? Or do you actually want something “realistic” for our present-day tech level [in which case @Karl is right on the money]?

Comment: If possible hard science and space opera. If I had to choose hard science.  Thank you for alerting me to these tags.

Comment: @Michael Kutz I was thinking solar mass ejection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With current technology, the most you can do is hope. Hope that it doesn't happen, that if it happens it doesn't come towards us, and if it does come towards us, may an eclipse happen so that the Moon shields us from it.

In the future, we may be able to build a [Dyson Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_sphere). If it has a radius smaller than 1 AU, it may protect Earth from flares (and coronal mass ejections as well). It is going to have to withstand these things in order to be stable anyway.

A civilization even more advanced than what it takes to build a Dyson Sphere may be able to manipulate stars into behaving. Such a civilization will have reached a point where science and technology are indistinguishable from magic for us.